# BASH: while read without echo + condition = strange behavior

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, while-loop

I have a problem with "if statement" inside while read loop.\n

Example 1:

```
81 function processconfig2()
82 {
83     pattern='^monthly'
84     while read line
85     do
86         if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]; then
87             echo $line
88         fi
89     done < /etc/logrotate.conf | awk '/^\/var\/log\/wtmp/, /^}/'
90     
91     exit 0
92 }
```

Output is empty.\n
After adding after line 89         echo $line:\n

```
81 function processconfig2()  
82 {
83     pattern='^monthly'
84     while read line
85     do
86         if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]; then
87             echo $line
88         fi
89         echo $line
90     done < /etc/logrotate.conf | awk '/^\/var\/log\/wtmp/, /^}/'
91  
92     exit 0
93 }
```

I've got proper output (condition at line 86 is processed properly):

```
/var/log/wtmp {
monthly
monthly
create 0664 root utmp
minsize 1M
rotate 1
}
```

Could someone explain to me this strange behavior, please.

Comment: because it's printing twice. Change line 87             echo $line"twice" in second example is a prove.

Comment: Thanks, looks more elegant and would increase efficiency.

Comment: You should comment the answer not the question (and possibly upvote and accept if you really like it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `awk` filter is on the **output** of your read loop. So when you don't echo the whole file you don't output enough for awk to match so it drops all output.

Try without the `awk` filter to see what I mean.

Alternatively move the awk filter to *before* the read loop (I imagine this was the idea anyway).

```
pattern='^monthly'
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]; then
        echo $line
    fi
done < <(awk '/^\/var\/log\/wtmp/, /^}/' /etc/logrotate.conf)
```

Comment: Thanks seems to work with variable defined before while loop and provided by <<< to 'done' at the end of the loop.

Comment: @ForColleague My example works as-is in bash. If it doesn't work for you then your shell probably doesn't support `<(` "Process Substitution" or something. A here-string (as in your answer) will also work but requires reading the file contents into memory in a way that this doesn't. Also you aren't providing anything to `done` you are redirecting standard input which `read` then reads from.

Comment: Yes, it works also. Thanks. My example as you see is less elegant. P.S For me this whole bash behavior is akward.

Comment: @ForColleague What about this do you think is awkward? The process substitution? The here-string? Your initial problem wasn't a bash issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another working example:

```
81 function processconfig2()
82 {
83     pattern='^monthly'
84     content=`awk '/^\/var\/log\/wtmp/, /^}/' /etc/logrotate.conf`
85     while read line 
86     do  
87         if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]; then
88             echo $line"twice"
89         fi
90     done <<< "$content"
91     
92     exit 0
93 }
```